# Comparison of Equal Double Values in Java

Tags: java, double

I am comparing 2 double values which I receive from user input.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter two numbers: ");
  Double a = scan.nextDouble();
  Double b = scan.nextDouble();
  if (a>b){
   System.out.println("Largest is: " + a);}
  if(b>a){
   System.out.println("Largest is: " + b);}
   System.out.println(a+""+b);
  if (a==b){
    System.out.println("Largest is: " + b);}
  }
}
```

This code works when I input double values that are greater than/ less than each other. However, this code does not work when I input two of the exact same double values(for example: `9.0` and `9.0`)
Why is this?
*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Double is an object. Use `.equals()`

Comment: You are asking whether `a` Object is the same Object as `b` Object

Comment: Don't mess around with `.equals()`.  Just use `double` when you need `double`, and `Double` when you need `Double`.  In this case, you need `double`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Like @GBlodgett and @ScaryWombat said in the comments, a `Double` is an object, so in my code, I basically compare if the objects are the same.
So to compare the 2 double values I can do:
`a.equals(b)` or use .compare() function like this: `Double.compare(a,b)==0`
However, I wouldn't need to do this at all if I just use `double` instead of `Double`